# What are the different ways of Visualizing Textual Data?

Tags: visualization, text-mining

I've recently scraped some textual data from the web and after removing stop-words and punctuations/symbols etc. created a `WordCloud` to get the most frequent words. What I'm interested in is in knowing if there are other ways of visualizing text data other than a word cloud? (regardless of the purpose)

- Code Examples are highly welcomed.
- Links to relevant articles would also be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are on the correct path. Wordclouds can be used to visualize the most frequent words (unigrams). But it can also be used to visualize bigrams , trigrams and so on. These links will be helpful:

[Article 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-visualisations-for-text-data-analysis-fc8add8796e2)

You can also use the `Spacy` library to visualize relationships between parts of speech (POS).

[Article 2](https://www.numpyninja.com/post/nlp-text-data-visualization)

You can also plot a bar chart between POS and their frequency as shown in this article:

[Article 3](https://regenerativetoday.com/exploratory-data-analysis-of-text-data-including-visualization-and-sentiment-analysis/)

**Cheers!**

Comment: This helps me a lot, the only thing is **Article 1** is a member only story on medium, can't refer to it frequently without a membership. Fortunately, I am a member. Other links are accessible freely. Accepting this answer, Thanks!

Comment: @FardeenKhan You can try opening it in icognito mode if you are not a member. It works sometimes. Glad to be of help!